# Why does my Windows Application Packaging project think my solution is a net 6 solution?

Tags: winforms, desktop-bridge, msix

My solution is a net 5 solution. I've been through all of the nuget packages to make sure they are all 'net5' compatible and checked that all the .csproj target frameworks do indeed say net5.0 yet when I go to package my application (MyProj.Installer - Windows packaging application) it shows me a warning:

> Warning   NU1702  ProjectReference 'C:\Users\rich-\source\repos\MyProjGit\MyProj\MyProj.csproj' was resolved using '.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0' instead of the project target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'. This project may not be fully compatible with your project. MyProj.Installer    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  1718

I have no idea where it is getting .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1 from as the oldest version my project has ever been is 4.7.2 but more to the point it thinks it is a net6 application when it is a net5 application.

It goes through and packages the app as an msix file and I can install it after signing of course however the app fails to launch and I believe the reason is down to the warning I describe above. Am I missing any steps for packaging a net 5 application? I've taken the exact steps I have for a net framework application that have worked in the past.

Answer (score 0):

So the app not loading was two fold. The app primarily didn't load as Entity Framework core 5 is referencing the wrong version of SQL Client. See https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/652.

The second reason why the app wouldn't load was because the msix was trying to access a file I had open on another networked computer. See the section common problems https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/tool-known-issues.

Still no idea why the packaging project think it is net6 howwever.